# How to prevent python for giving away file path when sending email?

Tags: python, smtplib

Here is my python code for sending email. I always use an absolute path for attachment
when email was sent its always give away for dir structure for example
attachment will be named home/user/mail/filename.xls.

here is what I did
using os.chdir change to working dir then send an email which is working attachment no longer giving  away dir structure but its taking more time for sending an email
like increasing more 70 secs. What could goes wrong ?

```
def send_mail(attribute):
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(fatt, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'+fatt+'"')
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    if isTls:
        smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username,password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

Comment: `"...filename="' + os.path.basename(fatt)`…!?

Comment: **You** are giving the full path in `'attachment; filename="'+fatt+'"'`, smtplib then passes what you want... Just change `fatt` with a more sensible content.

Answer (score 1):

#### An Alternate Solution - Path Splitting

You can use `os.path.split` to separate the pathname into (head, tail) pair. The tail would be the file name as intended to fetch. For eg:

```py
>>> os.path.split("/home/gavin/Desktop/gavin.jpeg")
('/home/gavin/Desktop', 'gavin.jpeg')
>>> os.path.split("/home/gavin/Desktop/gavin.jpeg")[-1]
'gavin.jpeg'
```

Your changes in your code would look like:

```py
from os.path import split as path_split

def send_mail(attribute):    
    ...
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="{path_split(fatt)[-1]}"')
    ...
```

---

#### Compare Path Splitting with os.chdir

Path Splitting via `os.path.split` is essentially a string manipulation operation. There are certain rules that define how data is stored in a given context, it follows those rules to make sense of the path and give a consistent result.

The `os.chdir` API changes the current working directory in the context of your program. The OS directive would check for permission, validity & existence of the file on disk. This is a very big change as compared to splitting a string at some index in memory.

An execution of `chdir` will trigger a `sys.audit` ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)). It executes hooks added by internal and third-party libraries. Libraries add hooks to maintain state consistency among other things - I've used this to invalidate caches for a certain CLI tool too.

You don't need to change the directory to fetch the file name of a given path. Depending on how many times you invoke `os.chdir`, the number of implicit actions it triggers is compounded, thereby increasing the execution time.

Comment: You can also use `os.path.basename` but I don't think it'd produce similar results on a Windows machine iirc (don't have a Windows machine but have memory of having a similar discussion)

Comment: Thank you my friend. But could you please clarify me what cause more 70 secs running time when using os.chdir().

Comment: Updated my answer to address the same. Hope that helps.